# Tensorflow: Dynamically Make Letter Prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to use the LSTM module in Tensorflow to use a one-hot letter prediction at time (t-1) as input into the next state at time (t). I am doing something along the lines of:

```
one_hot_dictionary = {0:np.array([1.,0.,0.]),1:np.array([0.,1.,0.]),\
                         2:np.array([0.,0.,1.])}
state = init_state
for time in xrange(sequence_length):
    #run the cell
    output, state = rnn_cell.cell(input,state)

    #transform the output so they are of the one-hot letter dimension
    transformed_val = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(output, W_o, b_o)

    #take the softmax to normalize
    softmax_val = tf.nn.softmax(transformed_val)

    #then get the argmax of these to know what the predicted letter is
    argmax_val = tf.argmax(softmax_val,1)

    #finally, turn these back into one-hots with a number to numpy
    #   array dictionary
    input = [one_hot_dictionary[argmax_val[i]] for i in xrange(batch_size)]
```

However, I get the error:

```
input = [one_hot_dictionary[argmax_val[i]] for i in xrange(batch_size)]
KeyError: <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor object at 0x7f772991ce50>
```

Is there any way these one-hot letters can be created dynamically with my dictionary from the argmax values to the one-hot letter encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you could achieve this.

The most direct adaptation of your code would be to use the [`tf.gather()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#gather) operation to select rows from an identity matrix, as follows:

```
# Build the matrix [[1., 0., 0.], [0., 1., 0.], [0., 0., 1.]].
identity_matrix = tf.diag(tf.ones([3]))

for ...:

  # Compute a vector of predicted letter indices.
  argmax_val = ...

  # For each element of `argmax_val`, select the corresponding row
  # from `identity_matrix` and concatenate them into matrix.
  input = tf.gather(identity_matrix, argmax_val)
```

For the case you showed where there are only 3 different letters, the performance probably isn't critical. However, if the number of letters (and hence the size of `identity_matrix`) is much larger—compared to the batch size—you could achieve better memory efficiency by building a [`tf.SparseTensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/sparse_ops.html#SparseTensor) and using the [`tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/sparse_ops.html#sparse_tensor_to_dense) op to build `input`.

Comment: One-line fixes--my favorite. Thank you!